# Difficulty verifying hibernate update queries inside a transaction with test code

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, testing

I am running into quite a bit of frustration trying to writing the verification portion of my test code for hibernate DAOs that use direct sql queries to update the db within a single transaction.

Background:

- Using Hibernate 4.1 with Spring 4
- Transaction boundaries are controlled via `@Transactional` annotation / `JpaTransactionManager`
- We for the most part just use hibernate as a JPA implementation and avoid most things hibernate-specific; i.e. we don't ever interact with a `Session` object directly.

Situation: I have a DAO that performs a direct SQL/HQL update using a NamedQuery. The main driver to perform the update this way (as opposed to calling `entityManager.persist`) is the problem of the detached object. I don't want to have to re-fetch the object just to persist save back my changes to it. The reason the object is detached is because it is cached.

I want to write a unit test that calls this DAO's update method, and then calls the DAO's find method to pull back the object fresh from the database to verify the changes were made correctly. Another catch is that I want this unit test to be run within a transaction (i.e. a subclass of `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`) so that the changes are rolled back and the state is left clean for the next test.

**Crux of the problem:** When I call the find methods on the DAO after the update has been performed, Hibernate apparently knows nothing about the change that has taken place. I assume this is due to some caching or something within hibernate that it is not able to pick up these changes for some reason. I've tried to look for this cache and invalidate it; no success thus far.

Example:

```java
@Test
public void testUpdate() {
    SomeUser obj = makeSomeUser("joe");

    // update the name using a NamedQuery; does not call `persist`
    dao.updateName(obj.getId(), "bob"); 

    SomeUser found = dao.find(obj.getId());
    // This verification fails, it finds "joe" still
    assertEquals(found.getName(), "bob"); 
}
```

elsewhere...

```java
public void updateName(long id, String newName) {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE USERS set NAME = :name WHERE id = :id");
    query.setParameter("name", newName);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

The only way I've gotten around this in the past is:

1. Don't run test within a transaction, then perform manual cleanup afterwards. I'd really like to avoid this as it is bad practice in my opinion.
2. Use `entityManger.createNativeQuery` to perform the verification step which is able to detect the updated changes. I'd like  to avoid this because it is inconsistent and ends up duplicating code just for testing sake. I'd like to use the same lookup code in testing as we do in the rest of the codebase...

Is there an easy answer I have just missed? Am I perhaps doing things in a non-hibernate-friendly way? Is there a better way to test hibernate DAO's?

Comment: Old post but I was wondering if you ever had an answer to this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

It may help if you view your repository integration test as taking the same place in your architecture as the services into which you typically inject your repositories. With this in mind, you can place the `@Transactional` annotation (from spring-tx) on your test, to demarcate the transaction boundary. This allows the test to insert/update test data, and to examine the database during the transaction, and for all of this to be cleaned up automatically when the transaction rolls back at the end of the test (which it will).

In the system I'm working on, all of our integration tests are written using this strategy. They all have this form:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/integration-test-context.xml")
@Transactional
public class ThingRepositoryIT {...}
```

We always start with an `@Before` that configures the data we need using:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

to get a handle on a jdbc template that can run run scripts that create our test data.

Also, we often have to call `flush()` on the hibernate session within our tests to ensure that hibernate has written its cached data to the database before we test it in our tests.

Answer (score -2):

First of all. Why bother testing DAO's? You should only focus on an integration test through proper service that has some real value and feedback. There's no transactions going on if you operate outside of services which are meant for that.

This `updateName` function is weird. When performing updates on an entity in JPA, we in most cases pass in an updated entity and get the new values which we set to the entity to be updated. What does the `makeSomeUser()` method in fact do? Is it persisting the entity? Provide more code. If you want to test update, you need to have a persisted entity, you have to know what you want to update, by obtaining the id, perform a lookup on database based on that id, if returns a matching entity then perform update operations on that returned entity. At the end of transaction all the changes will be persisted. Your approach to test is wrong here.

Comment: I tried to indicate that the `makeSomeUser` was indeed persisting the entity by referring to `obj.getId()` as the primary key.

Comment: (whoops. hit enter too soon.) I also gave the reason for why I wanted to use this kind of update pattern. It is for the detached object state. I have this object cached in memory and do not want to have to re-fetch it just to save it back. That seems wasteful.

Comment: (argh!) The reason why I want to even test the DAOs to begin with is because they have code in them... I want to rigorously test the SQL statements to make sure they are doing exactly what I want them to do, in such a way that is more difficult to do at a higher integration-test level.

Even if I say I am testing the service object / manager instead of the actual DAO, it is still all within a single transaction and I run into the same situation.

Comment: So you would have separate update methods for all the different properties? That's more waste and looks ugly. If you simply want to test your update which seems rather simple by the looks. Then you just call the setters on the persisted object and they will be saved at the end of the transaction. But this way of doing it has zero value for you, no feedback from the test whatsoever. You can't save the new values and try to query for the entity if it's not merged, can you show what does the updateName do?

Comment: It is not wasteful if you have a single property that changes frequently and if loading the entire entity graph is expensive. I know the example in my question is rather trivial, but still think it is representative of a basic problem I've run into several times w/ testing hibernate, and I was trying to avoid implementation specifics...

Comment: May I ask, why do you even use Hibernate here for such simple operations? Hibernate is meant for object and data structure mapping more than just simple SQL queries that could be done easily using even jdbc template for example.

Comment: I suppose the idea was to keep one consistent way of accessing the database. Using JPA queries as opposed to native SQL queries gives us, for example, database-agnostic-ness. We get the database-independence of hibernate w/o having separate SQL queries for SQLServer vs. Derby, etc.

Comment: Well, Hibernate in general is meant for different purpose, lot's of developers/projects include the framework in their projects and later run into problems because of having no knowledge how to use it properly. If you plan on using ORM then you should also follow best practices that go along with it. In my experience this is a design flaw. Even when you only want a single method for updating certain property, do it proper ORM way, with passing an entity to persist.

Comment: I'd argue that the presence of such HQL in hibernate and queries more generally in JPA proves that doing this is not fundamentally a design flaw, but is at times necessary and good.

Comment: In that case you cannot do that. Hibernate doesn't flush the changes unless you manually force it or it's end of transaction, thus you won't get your updated result the way you try to.